# Read more functionilty in angular4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have several line of text in my paragraph I want to have read more if there is more then 5 lines. I am not getting like how to do the same

```
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</P>
```

how to do this in angular 4 or angular 2.

need help. thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is called Ellipsis.
Try :
https://github.com/thisissoon/angular-ellipsis or
https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate

Answer (score -1):

Just add string limit Pipe for your application
like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-limit?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html